# Crystal reports: how to duplicate group header text in footer

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report I have some nested groups, I wont the name/description of every group (it changes for every group) will be duplicated in the footer of the correspondant group header (in the footer there are group totals also). how can I do? thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste the field from group header into footer.